# How do I convert mcrypt_encrypt from PHP into .NET code?

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, encryption

I'm looking to convert this function from PHP to VB.  Could anyone help me understand why the output is not correct?

```
//get img
$img = file_get_contents('https://www.random.org/analysis/randbitmap-rdo-section.png');

//pad
$blocksize = 16;
$pad = $blocksize - (strlen($img) % $blocksize);
$paddedimg = $img . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

//encrypt
$data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'abcdefghijklmnop', $paddedimg, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

//output
echo base64_encode($data);
```

The above outputs;
`wYkugZmmsCHNwFOr7sAgk6yUU2I+2rOtBmXAIcPleue+dT4zIvkSA6UYmW6tickeoIbyCylxrb5n` ... 
[rest truncated but goes on and total is 29484 characters]

Here's what I have in VB;

```
  Public Sub GetBase64EncryptedImg()
    Dim Img As Byte() = Nothing
    Using wc As New WebClient
      Img = wc.DownloadData("https://www.random.org/analysis/randbitmap-rdo-section.png")
    End Using
    MsgBox(EncryptECB(Img))
  End Sub

  Public Function EncryptECB(Data As Byte()) As String

    Dim Key As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnop")
    Dim Encrypted As Byte() = Nothing

    Using rj As New RijndaelManaged()
      Try
        rj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        rj.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        rj.KeySize = 128
        rj.BlockSize = 128
        rj.Key = Key

        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()

        Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(rj.Key, rj.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)

          Using sr As New StreamWriter(cs)
            sr.Write(Data)
          End Using
          Encrypted = ms.ToArray()
        End Using
      Finally
        rj.Clear()
      End Try

    End Using

    Return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypted)
  End Function
```

The VB outputs;
`pVngUaXYYv1tJSPzjDuwKw==`

That's it, nowhere close to the right number of characters.  Where am I going wrong here?

EDIT: Re being marked as duplicate, that question/answer gives back a base64 encoded string.  mcrypt_encrypt doesn't, so I'm not sure how to apply the code in that answer.

EDIT2: That duplicate gives uses an IV value whereas the code above doesn't.  Would that not differentiate the two to deserve a unique answer?  Or is it as simple as removing the line setting the IV property of the `RijndaelManaged` object?

EDIT3: Completely reworked the question

Comment: The duplicate stores the encrypted result in a byte array `byte[] encrypted`. If you want to use that, change the method to return `byte[]` and change `return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)` into `return encrypted`.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you but mcrypt_encrypt returns a string (not a base 64 encoded string or byte array).  How can I get the exact same response?

Comment: Strings are handled differently between .NET and PHP. What PHP returns is a byte array disguised as a string, where the encoding of the script file determines the encoding to be used for that string. So you just got to do `System.Encoding.ThePhpEncoding.GetString(encrypted)` to get the same string out.

Comment: Great, that was the part I was not sure about.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you can't figure that part out, update your question with the code you use, example input and output (both PHP and .NET) and I'll reopen.

Comment: Thanks, I can handle the encoding part after it's done but I've just noticed another difference; The code in the duplicate uses an IV value whereas the one I'm porting doesn't.